# Divide the posts by days (MeteorJS)

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

I have

```
Posts - collection

Posts.insert({title:"1"}); - simple document

Template level subscription

Meteor.publish('all',function(){
  return Posts.find({sort: { createdAt: -1 }};
})

<template name="sss">
  {{#each posts}}
     {{title}}
  {{/each}}
</temaplate>

posts:function(){
  return Posts.find();
}
```

And I try to create

```
10 December
"some title"
"some title"

09 December
"some title"
"some title"
"some title"

08 December
...
```

But I have only

```
"some title"
"some title"
"some title"
"some title"
...
```

And I don't understand how to create this dates ?? I try somth like this

```
{{#if exist_10_dec}}
  {{#each posts}}
  ...
{{/if}}

{{#if exist_09_dec...
```

But this is complete nonsense! Any idea how to create this ?

Comment: I believe the proper term is "group by" days, not "divide" and you get that output because all you do is write the post title in the template. (which you also have a typo in -  `temaplate`). You'll need to write a Mongo (?) query to group the posts by month and day.

Comment: Watch my edit answer to your previous question to get an idea

Answer (score 0):

There are a ton of different ways to do this, but the simplest way would be to user the underscore library. First iterate through every object and set the date that you want as a header (i.e. December 10th). Once you've done that, try the following code:

```
Template.template.helper({
    'posts': function() {
        var data = [ 
                { date: 'December 10th', title: 'blah1' },
                { date: 'December 9th', title: 'blah2' },
                { date: 'December 9th', title: 'blah3' },
                { date: 'December 10th', title: 'blah4' }
            ];
            var groupedData = _.groupBy(data, 'date');
            var result = _.map(groupedData, function(value, key) { 
            return { date: key, titles: value }; 
        });
        return result;
    }
});
```

This groups the data by date and creates an object array where array['December 10th'] will point to every instance of a December 10th object. To get it in a format that your template can handle though, you need to map that to an array. Your template would look like this:

```
{{#each posts}}
    {{date}}
    {{#each titles}}
        {{title}}
    {{/each}}
{{/each}}
```

I haven't compiled this code exactly; but I did test out the grouping and mapping piece and it turns it into a usable array. Use this as a guide to get where you want to go.